# Event onclick dynamic

Tags: forms, angular, input, dynamic, onclick

i use https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form angular dynamic form. How is it possible to intercept the click event on every input field of the web page? I tried

```
<pre>
<df-question [question]="question" [form]="form" ng-
click="onContainerClick($event);"></df-question>
</pre>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the click to the tag, just in your `DynamicFormQuestionComponent` (`df-question`) add `click` event on the input field (code taken from the docs)

**HTML:**

```
<input (click)="onContainerClick($event)" *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" 
       [formControlName]="question.key"
       [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">
```

BTW, you were using `ng-click` which is not Angular, but AngularJS.

**TS:**

```
onContainerClick(event) {
  console.log('clicked')
}
```

**DEMO** (check console) https://plnkr.co/edit/MbwuhWJrJOwuW23ZbzsC?p=preview